# Most efficient way to reuse an HTML5 canvas's drawn content

Tags: canvas, data-uri, getimagedata, off-screen, putimagedata

I use an offscreen `canvas` to dynamically generate certain images based on the runtime value of certain variables. Once the image has been drawn on the offscreen canvas, I want to get it and use it in several places of my webapp.

**Strategy 1:** use the offscreen canvas's `toDataURL()` method to obtain a `data:` URI that contains the image, and which I can programmatically set on the multiple `img` elements in the page that are supposed to display it.

**Strategy 2:** use the offscreen canvas's `getImageData()` method to obtain an `ImageData` instance. Replace the `img` elements with `canvas` elements and call `putImageData()` on them.

Which strategy is more efficient memory wise? Which is more “idiomatic”? I'm trying to avoid duplicating the memory needed to hold the instances of the displayed images. Other suggestions?

Comment: By "use it in several places of my webapp" do you mean several places on the same web page or do you mean across posts?

Comment: In the same page (it's a SPA anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use canvas elements instead of img elements.

Then draw the in-memory canvas to the onscreen canvases. A canvas element can use another canvas as a drawImage source:

```
context.drawImage(inMemoryCanvasElementReference,0,0);
```

BTW, the imageData commands (`.getImageData` and `.putImageData`) are very memory inefficient because they build an entire new array of pixel data. They also lack performance because they are not GPU accelerated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works well. I only have to sort out issues with retina displays and devicePixelRatios…